# Create MYSQL table, with procedure for insert progressive numbers. Can i write PHP page to do it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'd like to have a PHP page for populate table with progressive numbers.
I use this sql for do it in manuale mode.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dowhile;

CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
 `id` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `used` int(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 4322554334;
 WHILE v1 <= 455323423 DO
 INSERT xxx (id) VALUES (v1);
 SET v1 = v1 + 1;
 END WHILE;
 END;;
DELIMITER ;

CALL dowhile();
SELECT * FROM xxx;
```

Can I transform it on PHP page?
I made a HTML page with forms for 2 variables:
start number
end number

```
<html>

<head>
<title>iNSERt</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Isert</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="input.php">
        <tr>
          <td>Start</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="start" size="9">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>End</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="end" size="9">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit"
          name="submit" value="Sent"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i make input.php?
thanks

Comment: and ? so what ? what is the problem ?  what about input.php ?....more precisions are required

Comment: The information you are providing isn't really helping us to help you.

Comment: I need to insert that SQL request inside php page. How can insert variable inside and sostitute 2 numbers range?

Comment: You'll need to tackle this in pieces: (1) work out how to call a stored procedure in PHP, (2) add that to your PHP page, (3) redirect afterwards using `header()`, (4) modify the call so the start and end parameter is passed. Each of these parts can be researched using a search engine.

Comment: I have a problem to insert procedure with variables into php code. I use it with constant, but i cannot insert variable.